# Does k-Median problem become any easier when L = C?

Tags: clustering, metric-spaces

In the $k$-median problem, $L$ defines as set of feasible facility locations and $C$ defines a set of client locations in a metric space.

The current best approximation guarantee for the problem is $2.675$ due to [Byrka *et al.*](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2981561)  Do we have any better approximation guarantees for the problem when $L=C$? If not, is it possible to show that the same $(1+\frac{2}{e})$ hardness of approximation holds when $L = C$?

---

I am aware that the $k$-center problem admits a $3$-approximation in the general case. And, that it can be improved to $2$-approximation when $L = C$. Moreover, both these bounds are tight in their respective cases. I am hoping for a similar behavior for the $k$-median problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, the $k-$center variant when $L\neq C$ necessarily is usually called $k-$supplier problem.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri I was thinking along the same lines. However, this idea will not work. The overall k-median cost would be dominated by the newly added clients that are present at the locations where a facility is not opened. The cost due to original clients would become negligle comparison to them. Therefore, this reduction does not create a gap between soundness and completeness cases.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Can I ask a question about k-median in plane? My questions is, suppose we run PTAS  algorithm for  k-median and the divide the plane into a grid that each cell form a rectangle. Now, if we consider each rectangle as a cluster, can we say this give us a constant approximation factor for k-median in plane? My problem is, I want, each cluster of k-median in plane have a rectangle shape and I try to make each cluster to have a rectangular shape.